# How do I run an external process without waiting for completion/return in python?

Tags: python

I have been trying to launch an application (like a web browser, calculator, etc) in a python script. The problem is that every function/library that I have tried makes the external program run in the python thread. The os.system() function makes the program run in the same thread. The python script should act like a launcher, terminating (finishing the script) after it has launched the program (web browser, calculator, etc).

(Ubuntu 22.10 bash)
os.system("/usr/bin/brave-browser")
this launched the web browser but did not run in an external process/thread: the python script waited until the process had ended before continuing execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to open web-browser I suggest using [`webbrowser.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open), it has one compulsory argument, which is URL of page to open, simple example

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("http://www.example.com")
```